# Can a function be approximated by an infinitly often differentiable function with common values at the boundary of the Intervall

Tags: real-analysis, approximation, approximation-theory

Let $ f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R} $ be a $ C^1 $-function. Does for every $ \epsilon > 0 $ exist an $C^{\infty}-$function $ g:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R} $ such that $ g(0)= f(0) $, $ g(1) = f(1) $ and $ \vert \vert g-f \vert \vert_{C^1} < \epsilon $, where $ \vert \vert f \vert \vert_{C^1}:= \vert \vert f \vert \vert_{C^0} + \vert \vert f' \vert \vert_{C^0} $. If yes, is there any reference?

Comment: Approximate $f'$ by a polynomial $p$ and take $g(x)=\int_0^{x} p(t)dt+cx+f(0)$ where $c=f(1)-f(0)-\int_0^{1} g(t)dt$.

Comment: I do not understand, why g approximates my function f in the $ C^1 $- norm. When I differentiate g, I will always have the constant c...

Comment: You get $|c| <\epsilon$.

Comment: The Integrand in $c $ should be p(t), right?

Comment: You are right. Sorry about the typo.

Comment: If I understand it right, I could also use this scheme to find a function g such that also $ g'(0) = f'(0) $ and $ g'(1) = f'(1) $. And that this even even holds for the second, third,...derivative of g. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is right.